# Django - ModelForm ignores new field and doesn't show it in template

Tags: django

I have the following modelform in my application on production server:

```
class FullPolicyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ('name',)

    # common info
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 
    'float-none', 'style':'width:140px;'}), required=True)
    sdk_enabled = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    remote_config_time_window = forms.IntegerField()
    #more fields exists here.....
```

In my development environment I added a new field:

```
group_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'float-none', 'pattern':'^[a-zA-Z\d-_]*$', 'style':'width:140px;'}), required=False)
```

and I aslo added that field in my template as such

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3 float-none">Group name:</label>
    {{ form.group_name }}
    <span class="label label-info" style="cursor: help;" data-toggle="popover-ex" data-placement="right"
                              title="{{ field_description.group_name.0 }}" data-content="{{ field_description.group_name.1 }}" footer="{{ field_description.group_name.2 }}">?</span>
    </div>
```

I tested the code in the development environment and everything works as it should. Then I committed the code to remote repo and then pulled the changes on my production environment. Then when I opened the webpage, all the previous form fields were present except the new field (group_name), only the label and the span element appeared. What can cause the new model-form field to be ignored by Django?

**Notes:**

> I restarted the server using `pkill -f runserver` and I also `tried
>   sudo systemctl restart nginx`
>
> I didn't make any changes in my actual model, only added new fields to
>   the model-form.

**Edit:** I use nginx and uwsgi on AWS

Comment: Why is your production environment using runserver? You **must not** do that.

Comment: well I didn't setup the production environment, I was told that if I want to restart the server this is what should I use. Can you explain why I shouldn't use it?

Comment: Because the development server is explicitly not suitable for prediction, it is for development use only. That said, if someone rise set it up for you it probably *isn't* using it, which explains why that command didn't restart anything.

Comment: I see, I did some changes in the html, and ran pkill -f runserver, and the page changed according to the new html changes. But the Django changes still don't apply. What other way can I restart the server?

Comment: The server doesn't need to be restarted for template changes. But it's impossible to say how to restart it without knowing what the server actually is and how it is set up.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but the server runs on AWS. I want to clarify something, if I do template changes they take effect automatically, but if I make some change in Django components (models, forms etc.. ) there is a need to restart the server for the changes to apply? I tried manually adding changes to my form on the production server, but got no effect on the webpage

Comment: Yes, as I said changing HTML templates does not need a restart but changing Python code does. Now since you know it is running uswgi, can you do `sudo systemctl restart uwsgi`?